# How old was Broly when he was measured 920 of power level?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super Broly , Broly is measured his power level when he was a kid and the measure is 920. How old was Broly when he was measured 920 of power level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is impossible to point out his definite age, however, he was less than a **year old**. We know this because Broly was born in the *Age 732*. He was also sent to planet Vampa this year and his power level was **920** when he was scanned there. 
Note: This is based on the new *Dragon Ball Super: Broly*  movie. Previously, Broly was born during the *Age 737* and Vegeta was born during the *Age 732*. However, it seems that both Broly and Vegeta were born during the same Age.